# Malicious users acting as a gang and downvoting

Tags: discussion, down-votes

First, this is **NOT** serial downvoting. I have been hit 4 times by the same group of users burying a perfectly good (go with me) post because they can or are encouraged to. I have recently learnt though the comments https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226612/downvoting-due-to-personal-dispute-allowed-then-encouraging-downvotes-fromothe here that I am not alone.

Now I don't want to flood this is personal crap (my experience of the nasty internet people) but I really hate how not-seriously this is taken.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226612/downvoting-due-to-personal-dispute-allowed-then-encouraging-downvotes-fromothe

It is not fair they should do that, further that I get flack for complaining about it. I would like this issue to get some serious attention, ganged downvoting isn't on and there should be ways to at least report that one suspects it was some sort of personal act. If it is genuine patterns will develop.

I'll add info as needed, clearly my last attempt was not the right way to bring it to light.

Feature request because we have "serial down voting" sorted, it is automated.

(Note: I don't really care about the rep, it's the fact they can act like this and gang up, even though they've done no harm to me, I don't enjoy it, I loath the experience, I suspected the Lounge crew were at it again, so I join the chat, surprise! They are! That felt horrible, it was behind my back and there were a group of them, I then get the flack (where a moderator says "nothing to see, move on" and closes it for comments and puts it on hold!) for them downvoting an answer to deletion)

Comment: @devnull seriously?

Comment: @devnull let me flesh that out, I just posted that question because this behaviour just happened to me it was put on hold and locked, I want this issue discussed, and fixed.

Comment: **Where** does sbi ask for downvotes? He asks for *upvotes on his comment* and that people refrain from commenting **if** they were to downvote on your post. **Nowhere is he asking people to downvote your answer**.

Comment: I suggest you let this rest for a while; step away, get some fresh air.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ignore the specific case, also all the bitching/negative comments have been removed from that. So **they were removed between me posting the 'duplicate' and now**

Comment: Echoing Martjin , and Sometimes a cup of coffee does wonders.

Comment: @MartijnPieters until it happens again? 4th time! 2 of my meta posts are because of them.

Comment: What feature are you requesting here?

Comment: @AlecTeal: I looked at the transcript when you posted your first Meta post. I didn't see any direct calls for downvotes then either.

Comment: C++ lounge reminds me of reddit or something. kinda unprofessional language

Comment: I'm not here for /my case/ I am here because this happens, there's at least me and one other, I want it - the ability for this to happen - taken seriously, it isn't right it should be allowed to happen.

Comment: To repeat what others have said - looks like time to get up from the keyboard. Take the time to think about what exactly you expect moderators to be able to do about such behavior (assuming they can even confirm it).

Comment: @Oded in the comments of the locked question I do suggest several possible means of detecting this, just like serial voting can be detected. I do not have a tried-and-tested way, because I only have my 4 experiences. Surely it's a start.

Comment: @AlecTeal And it was explained to you how your metric for finding this behavior is not in fact indicative of inappropriate behavior; your criteria can, and often will, be met by entirely appropriate voting patterns.

Comment: Does gang-downvoting happen? Sure.  Is it worth actually doing something about it? Hmmmm, not *really* . Ignore it

Comment: @Adel what if that post had something useful in it? Isn't that the point of SO? This behaviour should be discouraged rather than ignored at least!

Comment: @AlecTeal - Of course the behaviour should be discouraged. I agree

Comment: @Servy once again, I have 4 cases! Give me a DB dump and some time before criticising my suggestions!

Comment: @AlecTeal You *have* access to a DB dump.  Take some time and come up with a refined proposal before proposing a suggestion if you're not yet ready for feedback.

Comment: @Servy link? I wanted discussion, I don't really want to be the person who solves it (surely that's a job for the ... I don't know team that maintain and created the SE network?)

Comment: Downvoting is something *that should happen* on this site. Something that **shouldn't** happen is posting a duplicate question just because you didn't like the response given on your first one. They're just reputation points. Everyone has posted a question/answer that they feel is very well thought out and then it gets several downvotes. It happens. Please, get over it.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen I don't like that it was locked and put on hold, there is an issue here and it ought to be discussed, that is why this one isn't about me and a specific case.

Comment: @AlecTeal If you wanted a discussion then why are you criticizing me for *discussing* your proposal and explaining why it is not a good idea.  If you want feedback on your proposal, then you've gotten some of it.  You know that your suggestion would cause more harm than good.  If you're not ready for feedback, then wait to suggest the proposal until you *are* ready for feedback.

Comment: @Servy it's not a proposal, yo know when you want to have something discussed, you may write to your MP about it, you do not post them a thick binding detailing a solution and implementation.

Comment: @AlecTeal You did tag your question "feature-request".  When asked what feature you were proposing, you stated a proposal.  In response to that proposal, I have explained why it's a very bad idea.

Comment: I'm requesting they add a feature to fix this, to deal with this when it occurs, right now none of us have any idea of the scale, or how many groups do this. The fact this is still open is encouraging, last time it was put on hold.

Comment: @Servy I apologise for confusing you, I have removed the tag, now you can see that I don't have a fool-proof no false-positives suggestion, just some starting ideas for an issue I get the impression you guys think I am fabricating.

Comment: @AlecTeal You've been told already, *many* times, that it's impossible to know why someone voted, either automatically or even manually.  Your proposed "inappropriate behavior" is in no way distinguishable from entirely appropriate behavior.

Comment: @Servy I've proposed the start of some useful filters, if you have 5 people that sometimes downvote within seconds of each other, from the same referrer and do this several times and never leave a comment... <--this is a start, once again, no DB dump, can't give you a refined solution.

Comment: @AlecTeal, 1) Users are not required to leave comments. 2) A link in a chat of ~20 people tends to bring multiple votes in a very short period of time.

Comment: @AlecTeal And I'm telling you, *once again* that that behavior can bee seen by users voting entirely appropriately.  There is no inherent indication from that behavior that they are voting on the user, rather than the post.

Comment: So what's the problem here?  is it that too many people downvoted the same post?

Comment: @SamIam read comments in linked Q

Comment: @AlecTeal You need to make your question self contained. It shouldn't depend on the comments in *this* question, let alone comments in *annother* question

Comment: @SamIam But in summary: link to OP's answer was posted on a chatroom, OP's answer was downvoted, probably from people following the link

Comment: @RichardTingle people OP has clashed with, then left alone, and done this thing on 4 times, and encouraged to downvote - with someone else who knows about the same group doing this to someone else.

Comment: I am a bit torn on this one. While it should be okay to link to an answer that's not stellar (which will most likely attract a few downvotes), I think repeatedly harassing the same user by doing this is **not** okay. This is what I believe the OP claims is happening, but the moderators don't see any evidence of irregular voting patterns.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ My point is that even if my cases are not strong enough, it is entirely possible for this to happen and no one to know about it. Mentioning it has not been a fun experience. I'm now debating conscripting a friend and employing random downvoting to make it an issue to get it discussed, clearly no one minds or cares!

Comment: @MartijnPieters While sbi is not directly asking for downvotes, you can't deny how that comment can be easily construed as an encouragement for downvoting the answer.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ so can any comment stating "-1, lousiest answer I've ever seen".

Comment: @AlecTeal Could you link to annother events where this particular user has directed downvotes at you? What we need to a pattern

Comment: @AlecTeal That is one example, one isn't a pattern. I'm looking for some more. That you could flag

Comment: I am so going to do that random down voting spree with some others. This has to be fixed. I hope telling you is insurance against being punished for it, but it's the best way to show something is bad (programs, insecure! It really is! -> No it isn't ->*demonstration*-> "Yes it is, very public apology! That'll fix this!")

Comment: @RichardTingle see above.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ: No, I don't agree. SBI is saying: avoid this guy, he's a jerk. That's his opinion, fine. **I** certainly don't read an invitation to go downvote in there; but I can see how others can then think: *Gosh yeah, SBI is right, I'll teach that jerk a lesson*, **but that's not the same thing**.

Comment: @AlecTeal *"I hope telling you is insurance against being punished for it,"* .... don't count on that.

Comment: @AlecTeal Doesn't really answer my request for the other examples you were talking about. This is going quickly non constructive

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've met the other people before, I avoid them now, they are not nice and it was certainly done with malice, I know this and know you cannot, but do not assume I am whining and feeling sorry for myself there is an issue here!

Comment: `"Should anyone of you visitors downvote this guy, do not leave a comment when he asks why, because he immediately went on a downvoting spray across my old questions when I explained myself."`  I cannot see how this quote can be **anything but** encouraging other people to harass this guy.  I don't think that harassment is something that the mods should take lightly like this.

Comment: @Bart you think auxiliary accounts are in order? Oh I feel a -D on my next SSH invocation! (sarcasm) but seriously, what if I am right and this happens to others who don't speak up about it, we have no data at all (we can't even speculate) on how frequently this happens.

Comment: @AlecTeal Ok, but just like the police a moderator can only act based on evidence. The other events are the evidence of a pattern that I'm looking for

Comment: @AlecTeal Just step away from the keyboard. Get some rest. And then move on from all this. The path you suggest you might be taking will lead to nothing good.

Comment: @Bart but it could lead to change and good for the wider community which is the point of SO! It shouldn't have to come to that though. I'm not upset about that, I'm a grown up! *stamps foot* I'm annoyed because this should be taken seriously!

Comment: It's probably too late to roll back the votes in this case, but we still do have a case of harassment-encouragement in the chat room, which probably ought to be dealt with

Comment: "48 more comments" O_o

Comment: @SamIam There are no votes to roll back to begin with.

Comment: @Servy interestingly now the post that started this has gotten attention, it's got 3 upvotes..... and no new down.

Comment: This is just going over the same territory it did before. If there's behavior that needs to be flagged, I hope that's been done. If so, it has or will be handled appropriately. We take things like this seriously. But don't expect things to *always* be perfectly fair. Anyway; I think this could stand for a cool-off period. I *strongly* advise against posting another question on this topic right away.

Answer (score 12):

### Linking is allowed

Linking to a post is absolutely allowed; in fact the chat system has special formatting to support this. This may draw additional attention to your post which may be good or bad. This may lead to downvotes if the post is bad

### Suggesting a downvote is not ideal, but with reasoning can be borderline acceptable

Downvoting is a privilege we trust people with and we expect people to respect that. People should always vote based on their opinion of a post, they shouldn't just vote blindly. So people shouldn't just ask people to downvote things blindly. Explaining that a post is bad and needs to be closed is also something that is generally allowed **but** again people should use their own judgement.

If a specific user is following you round then flag and ask a moderator to intervene but if your posts are simply poorly received then there is nothing which can be done about that.

### Judging why a single vote was made is impossible

This request is based upon a group of people all downvoting your post. This is exactly what normally happens and there is no way to tell why that vote was cast (withough being the person who voted). As such it is impossible for these votes to be considered invalid.

Comment: And I wouldn't change it, just like up/downvoting is allowed, sometimes I look at a user and think "wow that's 3 good questions" and they actually deserve upvotes, my record is 7 I think, from the math site, they were not reversed. Clearly the system can detect serial upvoting quite well, The rep was not falsely removed.